# can anybody explain life cycle of activity in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Activity Life Cycle - difference between onPause() and OnStop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-difference-between-onpause-and-onstop)

Can anybody explain the life cycle of an activity in android? In my program or activity I called only `oncreate()` but I didn't call `onstart()` and `onpause()` method. Will `onstart()` and `onpause()` be called by default?

Thanks

Comment: you also need to edit your question, the second sentence is unclear.

Comment: These are callback methods and you are not suppose to invoke that!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you've [seen this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) right? Doesn't that explain all you need to know?

(Note: each of these methods, like onCreate() and onStart() and onResume() and onPause() are called *automatically*, you don't need to call them. You should only override these methods if you want to do something at that part of the Activity lifecycle.)

[image]